# Why did Omni-Man fight all Guardians of The Globe by himself?

Tags: invincible

**Spoilers for TV Show - Invincible (Amazon Prime)**

At the end of the first episode,

> Omni-Man lures the Guardians of the Globe into their HQ. He then fights them by himself. This seems to be a hard task even for Omni-Man, as he gets beaten by the Guardians multiple times, wounding him heavily. Eventually he manages to kill all of them, but his wounds and fatigue make him drop to the floor. The GDA (Global Defence Agency) arrives at the scene shortly afterwards, and Omni-Man is taken into their hospital, where he spends a week or more in a coma, implying he suffered a lot of damage. All of the Guardians are declared dead and the GDA suspects someone from outside attacked, and managed to kill them, but not Omni-Man.

His reasons for doing that are revealed in the Season 1 finale. However, it feels out of character for him to carry out the deed all by himself. Also, his species (Viltrumites) are mentioned to be super intelligent and resourceful. His being at the scene of the incident is an instant reason for someone to doubt him (this is proven right, as that's how Art Rosenbaum later identifies Omni-Man as the culprit). There are many other ways he could have done that without getting himself involved.

> Luring them into the HQ and demolish it with a bomb, for example? Then finish off the ones who are alive?

Why take the hardest path?

Comment: It strikes me that he didn't anticipate that he would end up losing consciousness, hence wouldn't have been found at the scene and would have had to time clean up (or maybe collapse the base).

Comment: Note that at least four of the guardians would be effective impervious to a normal IED

Comment: What makes it the hardest path? Given you've seen the finale, and these are heroes, who would have helped him with this task, even if they understood why he was doing it? The season finale goes into the fact the not only will Omni-man live for "thousands of years", but also that he's a sleeper agent for the conquering of Earth by Viltrum. I'm sure even super villains would have something to say against that,  even if they normally wouldn't help the heroes....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no in-universe reason given for him attacking them all at once. As you say he explains *why* he did it, but doesn't ever mention why he faced all of them on his own.

In the comics (Issue #7) it happens *slightly* differently:

> Nolan isn't seen as he kills the members of the Guardians of the Globe. It's just that easy for him to kill them. We aren't even treated to a fight scene. He kills a member each frame and only after decapitating The Immortal do we see Nolan for the first time. He doesn't pass out, wasn't hit at all.

Changing the scene allowed Debbie to have more of a role, it builds the tension for the rest of the season, and keeps the watcher on their toes.

That being said we can we can speculate however, and the best reason I can come up with is just **arrogance.**

He could have tracked them and killed them one-by-one, but doing so would take time and might tip off the rest of the team. To use a bomb or another weapon simply goes against his nature. No Viltrumite is seen using something other than their hands in the series. When you can easily shrug off attacks like that yourself why even bother using them against your enemies, knowing your fist can do more damage?

Nolan was arrogant, pure and simple. He thought he was stronger and faster then the Guardians of the Globe, and thought he could kill them all by himself. And he was, barely.

Comment: Neat, I was curious if the comics had more insight.

Comment: And here I was thinking that the Viltrumites in the streaming series—and Omni-Man in particular—were rather tediously overpowered because, among other things, Omni-Man could take on the seven next-most-powerful super-people on the planet and still win, if barely. But in the comics, it apparently goes to even more extreme levels.

Comment: Though it's tedious enough even in the series. Will the half-Viltrumite Mark win a fight against any Viltrumite he goes up against in the series? Up until now, 0 for 4. Maybe you thought the one-of-a-kind superweapon who can manipulate the fundamental structure of reality could be nearly as good a Viltrumite? No, she abjectly loses a fight against Mark in an alternate universe and decides that she cannot contribute anything when he is fighting his father. Maybe the alien specifically created to fight Viltrumites could take them on? Up until this point, not so much.

Comment: Even the leader of the galactic confederation against the Viltrumites is a Viltrumite, albeit covertly, as if to say that even in that case, only Viltrumites can oppose Viltrumites. Although considering that three Viltrumites can just show up at their main planet and go around murdering people, one questions how they are even able to resist the obvious superiority of the Viltrumites at all. I guess one supposes that a group that decided murdering each other was the best path to galactic power might not realize that.

Answer (score 3):

**To do otherwise would not have been the Viltrumite way**

Earlier in the episode, Omni-Man explains that the Viltrumites go rid of all their "weak" people by literally beating each other to death until only the strong were left. Then they decided this gave them the right to rule over every other civilization. These people do not value subtlety and they are supremely arrogant. Asking for help or using a sneaky bomb would be admitting weakness. If Omni-Man wasn't capable of beating them to death, then he wouldn't be a worthy Viltrumite at all.

Comment: This does also explain why he's not been sneakily killing them off over the years.

Answer (score 1):

This does get (partially) explained later in the comics. I'll have to search for it, but he mentions that he's already wavering in his dedication to the Viltrumite Empire, and wanted to do it quickly before he could change his mind/stop himself (or something along those lines).

I was just reading through the TPBs, so it'll take me a bit to find it again, but I'll throw it up here when I do.

Comment: This answer would be much improved by adding the quotes rather than your vague rememberings